# Sqlalchemy: Many to Many relationship error

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

Dear everyone, I am following the Many to many relationship described on http://www.sqlalchemy.org/docs/mappers.html#many-to-many

```
#This is actually a VIEW
tb_mapping_uGroups_uProducts = Table( 'mapping_uGroups_uProducts', metadata,
    Column('upID', Integer, ForeignKey('uProductsInfo.upID')),
    Column('ugID', Integer, ForeignKey('uGroupsInfo.ugID'))
)

tb_uProducts = Table( 'uProductsInfo', metadata, 
    Column('upID', Integer, primary_key=True)
)
mapper( UnifiedProduct, tb_uProducts)

tb_uGroupsInfo = Table( 'uGroupsInfo', metadata, 
    Column('ugID', Integer, primary_key=True)
)
mapper( UnifiedGroup, tb_uGroupsInfo, properties={
    'unifiedProducts': relation(UnifiedProduct, secondary=tb_mapping_uGroups_uProducts, backref="unifiedGroups")
})
```

where the relationship between uProduct and uGroup are N:M.

When I run the following

```
sess.query(UnifiedProduct).join(UnifiedGroup).distinct()[:10]
```

I am getting the error:

```
sqlalchemy.exc.ArgumentError: Can't find any foreign key relationships between 'uProductsInfo' and 'uGroupsInfo'
```

What am I doing wrong?

EDIT: I am on MyISAM which doesn't support forigen keys

Answer (score 2):

Existence of foreign key definitions in SQLAlchemy schema is enough, they are not mandatory in actual table. There is no *direct* foreign relation between your models, so SQLAlchemy fails to find them. Specify the *relation* to join on explicitly:

```
sess.query(UnifiedProduct).join(UnifiedProduct.unifiedGroups).distinct()[:10]
```